# Value on <input> Suddenly Change on Click/Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache, maskedinput

This is simple script using jquery, my main problem is 
Step 1: click row no 5 [image: Step 1 when click row no 5]

Step 2: click row no 3 [image: Step 2 when click row no 3]

Step 3: click on input[image: Step 3 when click on input]

My question, **why data change when I click on input?** for your info in input I use custom maskedinput definition `$.mask.definitions['~'] = '[-_A-Za-z0-9 ]';`. Please help me figure it out. This is how I grab data from  :

```
for(var i = 0; i < _field.length; i++){
  if(_field[i].type !== 'money')
     $formWrapper.find('input[name=' + _field[i].id + ']').val($data.find('td:eq(' + (i + 2) + ')').html());
  else
     $formWrapper.find('input[name=' + _field[i].id + ']').val($data.find('td:eq(' + (i + 2) + ')').html().replace(/,/g, ''));
}
```

Here **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4DpJ/)** for your reference, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can get in touch with maskedinput developer, a workaround is call blur() to remask it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4DpJ/1/)

```
$('#step1').bind('click', function(){
    $('#i').val('').blur();
});

$('#step2').bind('click', function(){
    $('#i').val('1').blur();
});

$.mask.definitions['~'] = '[-_A-Za-z0-9 ]';
$('#i').mask('~?~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~', {placeholder: ""});
```